# codeception unit tests and symfony2 module

Tags: symfony, codeception

Since updating to the latest Codeception, I get the weirdest errors in my tests that used to work just fine.

I could  trace one of them back to getting the Symfony2 entity manager. For some reason, this line which used to work, doesn't anymore:

```
    $em = $this->entityGuy->grabServiceFromContainer('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

What's going on? The documentation mentions nothing, and I'm quite lost. The context is:

```
abstract class GenericEntityTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test {
    /**
     * @var \EntityGuy
     */
    public $entityGuy;

    public $cmf;

    public function _before() {
        $em = $this->entityGuy->grabServiceFromContainer('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $this->cmf = $em->getMetadataFactory();
    }
```

Comment: got one step ahead, replacing the $em = line with this:

      $em = $this->getModule('Symfony2')->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();

Shifts the problem to another place, but it re-appears as soon as a test fails with code coverage enabled.

Comment: After some more research, it appears that the whole old $this->someguy->grabServiceFromContainer() stuff has stopped working and repling it with the equivalent getModule() fixes it. There are still other isssues.